# background no se visualiza en iphone

Tags: html, css, html5

Los estilos de una pagina no se visualizan en Iphone ni en Safari ni en IOS  cargan los demas estilos solo esta habiendo problemas con el fondo y la opacidad de estos estilos

```
#mobile-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 18px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 998;
  background-color: rgb(0, 29, 126 , 0.9);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  left: -260px;
  width: 260px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usa la propiedad RGBA en lugar de rgb, rgba tiene el alfa y opacity

```
  background-color: rgba(0, 29, 126 , 0.9);
```

Comment: Correcto fue la solución muchas gracias

Comment: @GustavoLopezCallejas si fue la solución dale al clic de la solución o que resolvió tú duda.
Que estás satisfecho con esa.

Answer (score 2):

no es un tema de fallas lo que presentas, es más lo que puedes lograr con una notación que con la otra, se tratan de temas de opacidad lo que no te permite obtener tu resultado. Observa la siguiente respuesta dada en otra pregunta. Te informaras mucho más sobre tu inconveniente. Espero te pueda ser de utilidad

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538501/what-are-differences-between-rgb-vs-rgba-other-than-opacity

si generas alguna inquietud valida el cambio que puede haber entre:

```
background-color: rgb(0, 29, 126 , 0.9);
```

y

```
background-color: rgba(0, 29, 126 , 0.9);
```